# how to get a sub-directory with for-loop & find & if-statement in linux terminal

Tags: linux, for-loop, if-statement, terminal, find

### given the following structure:

```
.
├── a1
│   ├── q
│   ├── w
│   └── e
├── a2
│   ├── q
│   ├── e
│   └── s
```

I want a nested for-loop & find $ if-statement that has to work in the linux.

The expected output is the structures of sub-directory after checking if it contains a specific string in declared array.

### I want something like this code:

```
declare -a folderlist=("a1", "a2")
declare -a checklist=("w", "s")

for folder in "${folderlist[@]}";
do
  subfolders=$(ls ./$folder);
  for subfolder in "${subfolders[@]}";

    do 
      if [ $d == "w" -o $d == "s" ]; 
         then echo ./$folder/$subfolder;
      fi;
    done;

done;
```

### I wonder this part above:

```
do 
  if [ $d == "w" -o $d == "s" ]; 
     then echo ./$folder/$subfolder;
  fi;
done;
```

- How can I change [ $d == "w" -o $d == "s" ] part to something like if
  [ $d is in checklist ] ?

### Expected Ouput:

```
./a1/w/
./a2/s/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `find` for the whole thing?

```
# Test directory
$ find .
.
./a1
./a1/e
./a1/q
./a1/w
./a2
./a2/e
./a2/q
./a2/s

# Find sub-directories called `s` and `w`
$ find . -mindepth 2 -type d -name w -or -name s
./a1/w
./a2/s
```

### Multi-level find

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \( -name a1 -o -name a2 \) -print0 |
  xargs -0 -I{} find {} -type d -name w -o -name s
./a1/w
./a2/s
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've tried this and it works. But I'm afraid that the root directory ./ has too many directories to finding with keywords. Is there any other solution such as (1) Find 'a1' and 'a2' in depth 1 (2) And then find 's' and 'w' in depth 2?